# Проблема с выводом на экран

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имею код с проверкой на наличие папок и количества групп

```
$.post('http://192.168.100.67/vtnuft/count.php', "count" ,function(response){
  response = JSON.parse(response);
  switch (response['status']){
      case 1:
      $.each(response,function(key,val){
          if (key ==="count"){
              groupcount = parseInt(val);
              for (var i=1;i<=100;i++){
                  !function(i){
        $.post( "http://192.168.100.67/vtnuft/group"+i+"/check.php", function(response){
  response = JSON.parse(response);
  $.each(response, function( key, val ) {
      if(key === "check" && val === true){
            informationArray.push(i);
      }
      else if(key === "check" && val === false){
          console.log(i,"false");
      }
  });
}); 
    }(i);}
              var clonegroup = $(".clonein").clone();
    console.log(groupcount);
              console.log(informationArray[0]);
    for (var j = 1;j<groupcount+1;j++){
        if(j!==1){
            var diclone = clonegroup.clone();
            diclone.text("group"+informationArray[j-1]);
            diclone.attr("id",informationArray[j-1]);
            diclone.addClass("groupport");
            $(".leftcorner").append(diclone);
        }else{
            $(".leftcorner").find("li").eq(0).text("group"+informationArray[j-1]);
            $(".leftcorner").find("li").eq(0).attr("id",informationArray[j-1]);
            $(".leftcorner").find("li").eq(0).addClass("groupport");
        }
    }
          }
      });
      break;
      case 0:
      console.log('Произошла ошибка');
      break;
  }
});
```

Но проверяя `informationArray` выплыло, что проверка на наличие папок опаздывает и в `li`, который принадлежит `$(".leftcorner")`, записывается `group undefined`

Как решить эту задачу?

Comment: Вам нужно вынести спешащий код в отдельную функцию и вызывать ее, когда informationArray будет готов. Это называется callback

Comment: спасибо за помощь теперь работает

Comment: но только с одним, а когда два то выводит: `group17`, `groupundefined`, `group29`, `group29`